# Import/export when using reducers in Redux-React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm studying Redux with React Native and I have an example like this:

---

*reducer.js*

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux"; 
import {HomeReducer as home} from "../routes/Home/modules/home";

const makeRootReducer = () => {
    return combineReducers({
        home
    });
};

export default makeRootReducer;
```

---

*createStore.js*

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';

import makeRouteReducer from './reducer';

const log = createLogger({diff: true, collapsed: true});

export default (initialState = {}) => {
    const middleware = [thunk, log];
    const enhancers = [];

    return store = createStore(
        makeRouteReducer(),
        initialState,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(...middleware),
            ...enhancers
        )
    );
}
```

---

It works fine but I don't understand why I have to use `export default` in *reducer.js*.

When I try to use

```
// reducer.js
export makeRootReducer
```

and

```
// createStore.js
import {makeRouteReducer} from './reducer';
```

It didn't work.

Please help me by explaining it in detail.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about **named exports** and **default exports**...

Example of a named export:

```
export const someFunction = () => {
   // some code here...
}
```

Now you can import this in another file like this:

```
import {someFumnction} from './nameOfFile'
```

But if you do:

```
export default function someFunction () {
   // some code here...
}
```

That's a default export and you have to import it like this:

```
import someFunction from './nameOfFile'
```

In your example if you change this:

```
const makeRootReducer = () => {
    return combineReducers({
        home
    });
};

export default makeRootReducer;
```

To this:

```
export const makeRootReducer = () => {
    return combineReducers({
        home
    });
};
```

It will become a named export and not a default export and now you can do:

```
import {makeRootReducer} from....
```

Hope that clarifies... And here is more [info](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910)

Comment: But when i try to use it, i get an error like: 
TypeError: (0, _reducer.makeRouteReducer) is not a function. (In '(0, _reducer.makeRouteReducer)()', '(0, _reducer.makeRouteReducer)' is undefi
ned)

Comment: (0, _reducer.makeRouteReducer) is not a function

Comment: Oh there is a typo in your code... `makeRootReducer` and `makeRouteReducer..`. @NguyễnVănĐại

Comment: This is my app repo after i changed it by following your recommendation, but it still  don't work: https://github.com/daihalu/Booking-Car.git

Comment: I found it. Thank you @SakoBu